# NO_PUBKEY and KEYEXPIRED

Tags: linux, key, debian, apt-get

When I try to use `apt-get update` command on Debian I find myself in a kind of error cycle with these two errors: NO_PUBKEY and KEYEXPIRED

`W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
4D270D06F42584E6
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny/updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1356982504
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny/volatile Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DFD993306D849617
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-securty/dists/lenny/updates/main/source/Sources  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]`

First I get KEYEXPIRED error (with NO_PUBKEY but that's not the point now) then i tried this solution:

http://community.aegirproject.org/node/757/revisions/2077/view

(but I am not sure I did everything correctly)

`W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
4D270D06F42584E6
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny/updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9AA38DCD55BE302B
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny/volatile Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DFD993306D849617
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-securty/dists/lenny/updates/main/source/Sources  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.148.13 80]`

Then I get NO_PUBKEY error and I tried this solution and I turned back my initial problem :(

`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net` (8 digit key)

could you help me?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is bit late, however recently I came across same issue in ubuntu, and this is how i fixed that. first I've got the key from keyserver as below. you may need to change KEY and server according to your environment,

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 40976EAF437D05B5
```

after that you need to add the key to your key store (you may need to execute following as 'su' user)

```
gpg --export --armor 40976EAF437D05B5 | apt-key add -
```

found full details from here [GPG error: public key is not available NO_PUBKEY](http://tutewall.com/gpg-error-public-key-is-not-available-no_pubkey/)

Hope it will help (I'm also new to ubuntu, and that's how I sort out)

Answer (score 1):

I know, your Debian fix your question:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
4D270D06F42584E6
```

Just use that three lines code:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring

sudo apt-key update

sudo apt-get update
```